# Android FBConnect: unable to get extended premissions

Tags: android, fbconnect

when I login in and try get extended premissins displays "You must be logged in to Facebook to use this feature".
How can I get extended premissions for posting messages in facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Facebook Connect on the Android yet, but I have used it on a website. I'm thinking they are similar. I have two suggestions:

- Use [streamPublish()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish) instead of extended permissions -- although this will pop up a dialog every time you call it, or
- If you really have to use extended permissions, you have to call [requireSession()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.requireSession) before asking for permissions, to log the user in.

As I said, this is the way this should be done using Facebook Connect on a website. I'm not sure it's the same on Android, but I'm guessing it is.